# How do I display a new label text, selected at random, for a 1-day timespan?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Background: I have a button click event that triggers the parsing of text, selected at random [200], to be displayed to the user as a label.

Objective: Every day, display a new label text, selected at random, for the duration of that day until each text string has been used. Then repeat.

Example:

Today the user would see: COW

Tomorrow the user would see: PIG

Next Day the user would see: BEAR

Etc. 
200-days later: Repeat

I am still quite new to all of this and would greatly appreciate any expertise. I’ve included my code below for reference. Thank you in advance for your time.

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    string[] DailyAnimal_array;

    Random r;
    private long TimeSpan;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeArrays();
    }

    private void InitializeArrays()
    {
        DailyAnimal_array = new string[200] 
        {
            "COW! \r\n …”,
            "SHEEP! \r\n ... ",
            "PIG! \r\n … ",
            "DOG! \r\n …”,
            "CAT! \r\n ... ",
            "BEAR! \r\n … ",
            //etc. 200 total//
        };
    }

    private async void AllDailyAnimals_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        string DailyAnimal_Text = DailyAnimal_array[r.Next(200)];

        this.DailyAnimal_Text.Text = DailyAnimal_Text;

        AllDailyAnimals.IsEnabled = false;
        Intro_Image.IsVisible = false;
        AllDailyAnimals.IsVisible = false;

        //ADD CODE HERE FOR 1 RANDOM NEW ANIMAL (PER DAY DURATION) UNTIL EACH ANIMAL USED-THEN REPEAT CODE//
    }
```

XAML:

```xml
<Label x:Name="DailyAnimal_Text" Margin="10,10" TextColor="Purple"
    FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

<Button x:Name="AllDailyAnimals" Text="CLICK"
    Clicked="AllDailyAnimals_Clicked" Image="Animal_Button.png"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    WidthRequest="170" HeightRequest="170" TranslationX="100"
    TranslationY="100" IsVisible="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it would seem what you are looking for is how to persist data in your app.

Since your list of words seem to be pretty hard coded, you could probably get away with just saving a `DateTime` value to determine when the last value was selected and an `index` to the specific item. This way if your app is put into the background or killed of by the user, you will still know when the value was set and determine based on that whether a day has passed since a value last was selected.

To save simple values on iOS you would use `NSUserDefaults`, on Android `SharedPreferences` etc. Luckily nice people have abstracted that away for you in various plugins. What you may be looking for is the [`Xam.Plugins.Settings`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings) NuGet which handles all that stuff for you.

So add that package to your PCL and platform specific projects, then you can add values with:

```
CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("lastTime", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

And retrieve the time with:

```
var lastTime = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("lastTime", DateTime.MinValue);
```

Then if `lastTime` is `DateTime.MinValue`, it is the first time a user launched the app.

```
CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("lastTime", DateTime.UtcNow);
var index = r.Next(200);
CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("index", index);
```

Then use that index to set the text.

Now with those two set, you just need to handle the case when you come back to the App. You can simply do that by overriding `OnAppearing()` on your page and grab the `lastTime` from the settings and check against `DateTime.UtcNow`:

```
var lastTime = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("lastTime", DateTime.MinValue);

if (lastTime + TimeSpan.FromDays(1) > DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    // grab new value from the array
    // save the time
    // save the index
    // display it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it runs, but the label text parsed is still a new random value with every execution of my app, ignoring the day TimeSpan.  I wonder--could this have anything to do with my app testing being run through "Xamarin Live Player"?

Comment: Use the debugger and see what values come back from `GetValueOrDefault` and see if it is what is expected. Not sure if Live Player does anything special with NSUserDefaults, but try it without Live Player and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I am still trying to figure this out. I've determined the error is in my code.  Will you please clarify if you meant to rename my DailyAnimal_array to index?

Comment: Uhm no. The index is the random number you generate.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Cheesebaron and God's good grace I finally got it.  First, if you are using a Windows computer with the Xamarin Live player on an iPhone you need to change your Debug to Release in order for the Xam.Plugins.Settings to function properly.  I also needed to add a tickcount. I pasted the code below that worked for me.

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        string[] DailyAnimal_array;

```
    Random r;
 private long TimeSpan;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeArrays();

    }
  private void InitializeArrays()
    {
        DailyAnimal_array = new string[200] 
   {
  "BEAR! \r\n … ",
  //etc. 200 total//
  };
  r = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
        r.Next(0);

  private async void AllDailyAnimals_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {


  var lastTime=CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("lastTime", DateTime.MinValue);

       var index = r.Next(0,200);


        if ((lastTime + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)) >= DateTime.UtcNow)
        {           
            string DailyAnimal_Text = DailyAnimal_array[index];

            this.DailyAnimal_Text.Text = DailyAnimal_Text;
            CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("lastTime", DateTime.UtcNow);
            CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("index", index);
        }
        else 
        {

            index = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("index", index);
            this.DailyAnimal_Text.Text = DailyAnimal_array[0];



        }

        AllDailyAnimals.IsEnabled = false;
        Intro_Image.IsVisible = false;
        AllDailyAnimals.IsVisible = false;
    }
```